# My render looks pixilated and really strange

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

When I render my scene, for some reason my render looks pixilated in some places, and overall really strange. The image quality is 1920 x 1080, with 100% scale, and the render is at 128 samples. I can't upload the entire render but here is a section of it.

[image: 1]

Comment: This looks like denoising artifacts. Which version are you running ?

Comment: Thanks for helping, in the bottom right corner it says 2.92.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase sample amount. You might need 1000-20000 samples for an interior scene. You can use denoising to get away with less, but if you get results like you do, it means it's not enough. Adaptive sampling also helps. You could set Noise Threshold to something like 0.001, Max Samples to 5 000 and Time Limit to whatever time you want to render - something like 1-3 hours if you have GPU like RTX 2060 or something like that. This is all for Blender 3.0. You should use the latest version, it has many improvements and rendering is a lot faster. The values are just examples, see what works for you by testing.